# CompletableFuture not responding after worker thread send to sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, executorservice, fork-join

I'm trying to understand **ConsumableFuture**.
Basically, I supply a task to the ConsumableFuture and then put the worker thread running that task to sleep for 2 seconds. I expect the worker thread to resume execution after 2 seconds and return the result.

```
public class CompletableFutureDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.err.println("Application started");
        
        CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(()->work1())
            .thenAccept(op-> System.out.println(op));
        
        System.err.println("Application ended");
    }
    
    public static int work1() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("work1 called");
        return (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Application started
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
Application ended
```

Why is the worker thread not resuming?

But if I remove the sleep statement from the worker thread, then I get the desired output.

```
Application started
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
work1 called
Application ended
64
```

Comment: Common fork-join pool uses daemon threads. Your application is exiting because the main, and only non-daemon thread in this case, is exiting before the other thread can finish.

Comment: @Slaw thanks for the information. Fork-join by default uses daemon threads? Is there any way to prevent them marking as a daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved asynchronous operation as well as avoiding marking it as a daemon, by supplying my own instance of Executor. (Any flavour of Executor)

```
CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(()->work1(), Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
            .thenAccept(op-> System.out.println(op));
```

I think this would have avoided creating daemon threads, similar to what we have in ExecutorServices.

Thank you @Slaw for providing the information on the daemon thread. I would like to find out more why ForkJoin architecture would mark threads as a daemon by default.

Comment: But if you really need it, I believe you can create your own `ForkJoinPool` with a custom thread factory that returns daemon threads. The common pool can't do this because otherwise developers would have to manually shutdown the common pool (which is not user friendly). Of course, as it is you can't shutdown the common pool.

Comment: Correction: "...custom thread factory that returns **non-daemon** threads".

Answer (score 2):

As @Slaw already pointed in the comment, the Main thread completes and exit the application when the work thread is sleeping, so you can call [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--) to keep main thread waiting until work thread completes

```
System.err.println("Application started");

 CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(()->work1())
            .thenAccept(op-> System.out.println(op)).join();

System.err.println("Application ended");
```

Output :

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
Application started
work1 called
12
Application ended
```

Or you can keep main thread wait after completion of it work

```
  System.err.println("Application started");

  CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(()->work1())
            .thenAccept(op-> System.out.println(op));

  System.err.println("Application ended");

  completableFuture.join();
```

Output :

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
Application started
Application ended
work1 called
25
```

If you have multiple CompletableFuture objects then you can use `allOf` to wait until all tasks get completed (but in background every completable task will execute asynchronously)

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFuture1,completableFuture1).join();
```

Comment: CompletableFuture is usually used for asynchronous task execution. Let say if I have 4 tasks assigned to the ForkJoinPool, while some other task is running on the main thread. join() would block the main thread. And the purpose would be defeated. Any alternative approach to solve this ?